# AzureRM WebJobs Deployment with Release Management on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-webjobs, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to deploy AzureRM Webjobs with VSTS Release Management and haven't been able to find a good solution for it other than uploading it via FTP.  This way works, but doesn't handle when the schedule of the job changes.  Every solution that I've found so far refers to Classic Webjobs which won't work for jobs deployed to Resource Manager.

Comment: You may check these article and thread https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-ci-in-vsts/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458493/how-to-deploy-to-azure-resource-group-using-vsts-release-management

Comment: Why can't you use built-in "Deploy AzureRM Web App" step from VSTS? How are you specifying the schedule of the Web job?

Answer (score 0):

DavidDebbo created a sample for how to publish webjobs with ARM template here: [ARMTemplates/WebAppWithWebJobs.json](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ARMTemplates/WebAppWithWebJobs.json). You can refer to this for details.

Besides, you can simply add an [AzureRM Web App Deployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment) task in your release definition to deploy your webjob via Azure Resource Manager if you can see this task in task list.

> The AzureRM Web App Deployment task is used to deploy Web Apps and
>   WebJobs to Azure. The task works with the Azure Resource Manager APIs
>   only. The underlying technology used by the task is Web Deploy.
>
> **The task is under development and is available to a limited set of
>   accounts on Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)**. The video describes
>   the features that are available in the task currently.

Comment: I can see the AzureRM Web App Deployment task, however my build outputs the web app package and the web job as it's own package and when i deploy the job it just overwrites my web app. My app consist of one web app with 8 jobs under.

After looking at the video that you referenced Anand doesn't really go into details about how to publish the web job, he only talks about the web app package.

Comment: @Darnell So you mean you get two packages after your build?

Comment: i get about 9 packages after the build.  one for each job and one for the web app. @Eddie

Comment: @Darnell Did you try add more AzureRM Web App Deployment tasks to deploy the packages for webjob?

Comment: I did and the package was deployed to the /site/wwwroot instead of the jobs folder under the app_data.

Comment: @Darnell Did you check the "Exclude Files from the App_Data Folder" option in the task settings?

Comment: it's not checked.  
My current setup is one AzureRM Web App Deployment task for the API and then another one to deploy the jobs and the jobs overwrite the API  itself.